# WordPress - Promoting A Dev Build To Production

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, cpanel

I recently took over a WordPress site with the following directory structure inside of **/public_html**:

```
wp_config.php
/wp-admin
/wp-content
/wp-includes
...
...
...
/development
```

The root (production) site is pointed to **/public_html**.  Inside of **/public_html**, I have a sub-folder called **/development**.  This subfolder has its own separate installation of Wordpress with a directory tree that looks like:

```
wp_config.php
/wp-admin
/wp-content
/wp-includes
...
...
...
```

You can access this WordPress instance via *www.mywebsite.com/development*.  I am at a point where I would like to promote the development build to production.

What's the "WordPress" way of doing this?  This is hosted on a machine that can be accessed via cPanel.  I've noticed that while you can add "Addon Domains" and "Subdomains" via cPanel, you can't change the root public directory through cPanel.  I would like to avoid SSHing into the machine and manually editing the **httpd.conf** file since that can cause conflicts with cPanel.

Is there a functionality in either cPanel or WordPress to automatically take what's in **/public_html/development** and replace **/public_html** with its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking the **.htaccess** and **index.php** files from */public_html/development* and using them to replace the same files in */public_html*.

Once you replace the two files, open up **index.php** (inside of **/public_html**) and update

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

to

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/development/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

with *development* being the name of the subdirectory you got your **index.php** and **.htaccess** files from.

After you replace the above two files, go to your WP Admin console associated with the build you would like to promote to production and then click on "Settings" -> "General".  Find the **Site Address (URL)** input and update the value from `https://www.mywebsite.com/development` to `https://www.mywebsite.com`.

Comment: There's no 'wordpress' way of doing deployments. You have to check what was the workflow of the original team and follow that (or find a new way). About your answer, your changes will be wiped after the next update of WP. You should never change any file managed by WP, but rather do your changes in your theme (or child theme if you are using a theme that gets updates). I would read a bit more about 'good WP' practices as what you did above (edit index.php) is a **really**, **really**, **really** bad idea.

Comment: @Augusto You're confused.  The index.php being changed here is that of an installation which will no longer be used going forward.  The index.php in the active WP directory isn't being changed